# Redisson getAtomicLong - what happens if key does not exist?

Tags: redis, redisson, atomic-long

I'm building a cache implementation in Java using Redisson. I want to use it to cache a numerical value. So I'm using getAtomicLong() like so:

```
RAtomicLong userNumber = redissonClient.getAtomicLong("my-key");
long value = userNumber.get();
```

However, the docs aren't very descriptive about what happens here, and so I have a few questions:

1. Assume that "my-key" does not yet exist in the cache. What does getAtomicLong() return?
2. If "my-key" does not exist, what does userNumber.get() return?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a silly Java example program and did some experimenting, so let me answer *both* the question you actually asked and then question I think you were *trying* to ask.

> Assume that "my-key" does not yet exist in the cache. What does getAtomicLong() return?

An instance of `RAtomicLong`- because you *might* do something with the key/value in the future (like `incrementAndGet` or something).

> If "my-key" does not exist, what does userNumber.get() return?

Zero. Yes, not `null`, yes not an exception, just 0. This was reasonably surprising in my test program.

The *real* interesting part about the Reddison API is that it leans hard on the atomic stuff - great if you could be updating a value from multiple threads - but seems to not document the simpliest use case: I want to read or write from Redis and it's not a number / not atomic / my threads or data is structured in such a way that they won't clobber each other.

That seems to be what Reddison's `RBucket` stuff is for.

That *will* return a `null` if the object is not in Redis.

```java
         RBucket<String> back = client.getBucket("foo");
         String value = back.get();

         if (value == null) {
             System.out.println("NOPE, NULL");
         } else {
             System.out.println(value);
         }
```

I really wish that would have been documented better - looking back I see "bucket" as a container for stuff, but for a while I assumed it meant some advanced Redis pattern and not "a holder for a value of a generic type".

(If you really do want the fancy stuff, [there's an excellent baeldung artigle on it](https://www.baeldung.com/redis-redisson) ).